# Is there a way to live copy a channel chat from one server to another?

Tags: discord

I am trying to create a spreadsheet for a World of Warcraft community, based on certain posts/events happening where we @tag the involved people. We would then normally go to our excel sheet and enter manually the names of the participants and all the rest of the details.

I have been trying to do it with Zapier, and i managed to fix all my rules/steps, but the moment i @tag anyone, the text sent/parsed is " !185020918530048000> " instead of "Loco-Silvermoon" for example.

Please help, any insight would be most welcome.

Anyone got an idea about that? or any Bot/Platform that would work around that? My thought process took me two solutions. Either get a bot to replicate all the chat happening on that channel to another private channel that only i can see and where tagging is not allowed (no idea if that exists or work). OR, get a Bot with a plaintext option that would just send me the text instead of the tagtext.

Comment: Hello, can you include what language are you using? (Specifically, which Discord API are you using). If possible, can you please show us what you have done so far?

Comment: The format <@!123456789...> is how mentioned are sent. The client then displays the user name associated with that ID. That said, I tested this with Zapier and the initial message sent from server A to server B showed the mentioned user as expected. However upon refreshing my window, the formatted id was displayed instead. Note, if the user is in both servers it works fine, however if the user is not in the second server you may end up with the formatted ID. You could set your rule to include `Mentions Username`. This would list the username (separately) of any mentions in the message content.

Comment: @Kaynn, no clue. the bot I was testing is a 3rd party bot platform that you can give a set of rules on their webpage such as 'if a new message has been posted on this channel, retrieve it, the separate each line as a different entry, then blablabla' What i did follows the same logic, but i practicaly did 0 coding to share with you guys here.

Comment: @Anu6is the point of what we're trying to do is to catalog all the participants tagged in those events, automatically on an Excel sheet. It's why I was looking for a clear text out of the mentions, as userID wouldnt have been really useful. On that matter, I came out with an idea that would work, it's to catalogue the ID of every one in the discord channel in a different excel sheet and have our new sheet lookup said id and replace them, but that would mean a hell lot more work in the upcoming future, which we are trying to reduce.

Comment: I managed to find a bot someone posted on Github that does exactly what I had in mind for my other fix. all it does is live repost everything being written on a channel, to either another channel or even another server. Faced the same issue at first, where the ID would be copied and the guy would still be tagged, eventho he/she wouldn't even be on the server. After a quick talk with the guy, he suggested changing message.content to message.clearContent and voila, it worked like a charm. Now all I got to do is upload the bot to keep it live, and we're in business.

Comment: If you just need the tagged users and not the actual message content, you can simply send the `Mentions Username` like I mentioned in my first comment, You don't actually even need to send `Content`. If you do want to actual message contents as well then it seems as though you've found your solution. Cheers.

Comment: @Anu6is but i need Zapier to post that in an excel sheet. using the Mentions Username will put their discord ID on excel instead of their server nickname. ie: my username is Loco#0000 but my nickname on the server in question is Loco-Argentdawn. I need to have the Loco in a column and Argentdawn in another.... any idea ?

Comment: and my solution mentioned above didn't work for one reason. We post an event, with empty slots, then edit the post with the attending people with mention. the bot i got doesnt repost edits :/

Comment: The only way to fix my issue as far as i can see, is that i need a bot now that retrieve everyone's ID and Nickname from the channel and store them in a excel sheet, that i would have the other sheet lookup for said ID's... any thought?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know a way to get Nickname with Zapier.  [This](https://pasteboard.co/IxpUh2y.png) is the most I could do. Username and Discrim